# How to bind properties of a @State variable in a ForEach?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

```
class Form {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var fields: [FormField] = []
}
```

```
class FormField {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
}
```

```
struct LogCustomizationView: View {

    @State var form: Form

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(form.fields.indices) { idx in
                TextField("Name", text: self.$form.fields[dynamicMember: idx])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problematic line is:

```
TextField("Name", text: self.$form.fields[dynamicMember: idx])
```

The first error I got was

```
Missing argument label 'dynamicMember:' in subscript
```

So I added `dynamicMember:`, which is how it's shown above. Now the error I get is:
`Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'WritableKeyPath<_, _>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI errors can be really nebulous.

You are effectively trying to bind a `FormField` object to a `Binding<String>` where neither the object adopts `BindableObject` nor the `name` ivar (which you assumably want to bind) has a publisher attached to it (`@Published`).

I guess you want to bind the `name` ivar to the TextField:

```
  ForEach(form.fields.indices) { idx in
    TextField("Name", text: self.$form.fields[idx].name)
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm just starting with SwiftUI had no idea about publishers- your helpful explanation is appreciated.